# get the outcome of random.NextBoolean() and use it in further if statement

Tags: java, concurrency

```
public void waitingbay (Bus bus) throws InterruptedException
{
    synchronized (listBus)
    {
        System.out.println(bus.getName()+ " can park in " + bus.getSpot() );
        System.out.println(bus.getName() + ": Need " + bus.getOilchange()  + random.nextBoolean() + ", Need cleaning: " + random.nextBoolean());
        listBus.wait();
     }
}
```

From the above printline, I'm getting this output:

`Bus12: Need oilchange: false, Need cleaning: true`

Is there any way I can use these true or false in an if statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first save that random boolean result in an variable (if you don't store that result in variable, after calling `rand.nextBoolean()`, it's just gone, you can't restore that result no more).

You can achieve storing result of calling `rand.nextBoolean()` the following way:

```
boolean needOil = rand.nextBoolean();
boolean needCleaning = rand.nextBoolean();
```

After that you can much more with that random result:

```
if (needOil) { // If needOil is equal to true... 
    // do stuff...
} else { // otherwise...
    // do another stuff... 
} 

if (needCleaning) {
    // do stuff...
} else {
    // do another stuff...
}
```

---

If your intention is to use combination of both random results(following your comment to another answer), you should learn a bit about **logical operators** (e.g. AND **&&**, OR **||**) and use them properly:

```
if (needOil && !needCleaning) { // If needOil is equal to true AND needCleaning is equal to false...
    System.out.println("Needs oil and doesn't need cleaning");
}
```